# mongodb is not accessing from outside of the server

Tags: mongodb

Steps followed:

1. updated bindIp in the /etc/mongod.conf file
2. record entered in the iptables

   ```
   root@:/var/log/mongodb# iptables -L -n -v
   =============================================================

   Chain INPUT (policy DROP 108K packets, 5349K bytes)
   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       194.195.119.119      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1199 packets, 75946 bytes)
    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            194.195.119.119      tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
   ```
3. allowed ufw :

   ```
       root@:/var/log/mongodb# ufw status
   ===============================================
   To                         Action      From
   --                         ------      ----
   22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
   27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
   22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
   27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
   ```

bindIp works fine for 0.0.0.0 but unbale to start mongodb service when added actual ip ids
e.g. e.g.   bindIp: 194.195.119.119
bindIp: 194.195.119.119,103.208.71.9

and getting below error on start :

```
root@:~# systemctl status  mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-07-11 09:02:37 UTC; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 161544 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
   Main PID: 161544 (code=exited, status=48)
        CPU: 365ms

Jul 11 09:02:37 .ip.linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 11 09:02:37 .ip.linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Jul 11 09:02:37 .ip.linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Did you check the Mongo logfile?

Comment: hi @WernfriedDomscheit

'''
"msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"194.195.119.119","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
"msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Cannot assign requested address"}}}

'''
this is what log is stating but I am clueless here

Comment: Please put such additional information to your question (by "edit") instead of a comment. Looks like TCP port 27017 is already used by another process.